# Is it possible to set the color for the bottom region with `mlxtend.plotting`?

Tags: python, mlxtend

I am trying to reproduce the example in this [post](https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2015_singlelayer_neurons.html), which produces this figure.

[image]

The colored regions above are plotted by [`mlxtend.plotting`](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend) (version '0.14.0').

With the default settings on colab, this code

```
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
plot_decision_regions(X, y, clf=ppn)
```

produces this figure.

[image]

The data points have been plotted while the bottom region has not.

Is it possible to set the color for the bottom region with `mlxtend.plotting`?

Comment: [Issue](https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend/issues/589) has been filed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like a bug derived by the classification of two regions, if you try and separate 3 clusters as the following example it will work.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import itertools
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier
from mlxtend.data import iris_data
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

# Initializing Classifiers
clf1 = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)
clf2 = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
clf3 = SVC(random_state=0, probability=True)
eclf = EnsembleVoteClassifier(clfs=[clf1, clf2, clf3],
                              weights=[2, 1, 1], voting='soft')

# Loading some example data
X, y = iris_data()
X = X[:,[0, 2]]

# Plotting Decision Regions

gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))

labels = ['Logistic Regression',
          'Random Forest',
          'RBF kernel SVM',
          'Ensemble']

for clf, lab, grd in zip([clf1, clf2, clf3, eclf],
                         labels,
                         itertools.product([0, 1],
                         repeat=2)):
    clf.fit(X, y)
    ax = plt.subplot(gs[grd[0], grd[1]])
    fig = plot_decision_regions(X=X, y=y,
                                clf=clf, legend=2)
    plt.title(lab)

plt.show()
```

Try and ask directly on their github directory: https://github.com/rasbt/mlxtend

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible. You can use the colors parameter instead, I think it is much easier. You should try this one, is this what you are looking for?

```py
fig = plot_decision_regions(
  X=X,
  y=y.astype(int),
  clf=clf,
  legend=2,
  colors='yellow,red'
)
```

[image: Result Example]